# Unable to load dll arcgisversion.dll

Tags: arcgis-10.2, visual-studio, deployment

I'm trying to publish my VB.net Application, it's working fine on my machine, but it's showing this error on my friend machine:

> unable to load dll 'arcgisversion.dll': The specified module could not
>   be found.

I've checked platform and target cpu, they both are 86x.

What I have tried already:
 - releasing the project, which adds alot of dlls, the error remains
 - copying arcgisversion .dll from my pc to the target pc, and applying this command as Administrator :regsvr32 /i ArcGISVersion.dll, an error message shows up: "the module arcgisversion was loaded but the entry-point dllinstall was not found"

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you have tried already?

Comment: I've edited my question